# How is AI used in Internet of Things?

Tags: papers, applications

I would really appreciate it if someone would explain how AI is used in IoT. In the papers that I have found, half of the paper itself is about what IoT  is and very few information about how AI is used for it. Good paper recommendation or a book would also strongly help.

The papers that I found:

1. [Selected methods of artificial intelligence for Internet of Things conception](https://annals-csis.org/Volume_5/pliks/161.pdf) (2015) - Aneta Poniszewska-Maranda, Daniel Kaczmarek
2. [Artificial Intelligence in Internet of Things](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1049/trit.2018.1008) (2018) - Ashish Ghosh, Debasrita Chakraborty, Anwesha Law.
3. [The application of artificial intelligence in the internet of things](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9092454) (2019) - Wenbo Yao.
4. [Review on Artificial Intelligence with Internet of Things - Problems, Challenges and Opportunities](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8976588).

Comment: for me internet of things is about smart equipment, the applications are too broad, AI may not run directly on a single small equipment item but runs on server

Comment: an example is facial recognition on a "smart" camera

Comment: I edited your post to include the links to the papers you found. Make sure these links point to the correct paper.

Answer (score 1):

One application of AI in IoT is **cybersecurity**. If you are interested in this topic, this review [Role of Artificial Intelligence in the Internet of Things (IoT) cybersecurity](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s43926-020-00001-4) (2021) mentions many specific works and papers that describe specific experiments.

I don't know if you are familiar with AI techniques, like decision trees or neural networks, but one idea is to apply these techniques to detect anomalies in the traffic.

The following diagram of a decision tree (taken from the review) illustrates this idea

[image]

So, basically, you detect whether there's an attack based on the flow rate, size, and duration of traffic.

Right now, I cannot provide more details, because I don't know much about this specific topic, but, after having quickly skimmed through the paper and fully read the introduction, I think you will get answers to some of your questions if you read it.